# Restrict download of .htaccess and web.config files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am facing one problem. When I enters .htaccess or web.config after website url, it downloads the .htaccess or web.config file. (e.g. http://localhost/.htaccess). I am trying to restrict download but unfortunately not successful. I have tried with giving permission 600 to .htaccess, still it gets downloaded.

Comment: What server Is this site on, IIS?

Comment: This site is on nginx server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an ngix server that should do the job.
This part of code need to where you defined the rest of your server and location blocks

```
location ~ /\.htaccess {
    deny all;
    return 404 http://where_ever_you_want/and/so/on;
}
```

Comment: Where to make this change? In .htaccess file itself?

Comment: In the apache config file according to the [apache manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch)

Comment: I am using nginx server.

Comment: @MaheshGaikwad — Then how are you using .htaccess? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

Comment: Sorry for delay. My requirement is changed now. I need to show 404 page when user enters /.htaccess in browser. I tried with following, but not working as expected,

RedirectMatch 404 ^/.htaccess

Comment: please find the addition in my answer